# SharePoint app upgrade process with database -error temporarily unavaiable

Tags: sharepoint-online, upgrade, office-365

hello I recently began to develop apps for SharePoint 2013 online on my Office 365 account. And I am getting more familiar with upgrade process.
So I know how to upgrade app for SharePoint online. Only thing is to change version in manifest to higher version.

But my problem is that when I attach database to project(as `dacpac` file) then upgrade fails and generates error

> 'The content database on the server is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Details: 0x80070002 '

I always get this error. When I deploy app first time with database then everything is okay. But when want to upgrade database then I got this error.
I can add that app is autohosted.

Any ideas what causes errors?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumbled upon how do you do App Development with Least Privilege, so you don't want to do development with SharePoint Farm Administrator account, as you may potentially get access to other database in the farm, except the one you are interested in.

looks like you need farm admin privileges to access the DB, [this link](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Akhilesh/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10) is a solution to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to run your app can you look at the rest of the message in the output window.  For me I had some things missing or named wrongly in my Elements.xml file. I named 1 of my properties "Title" but it did not like that, maybe as it was ambiguous.  I also had to add a WebDisplayName to my property as I had the WebBrowsable property set to true.  Once I corrected these things it ran like a dream.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, I resolved it by just un-provisioning, deleting and re-adding the `SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`